# contact form 7 flips clickin on text fields

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, contact-form-7

There is a media query that flips the screen when landscape mode is detected (to somehow force portrait mode) for that I'm using this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

I'm working on a mobile version of a web page (that contains the contact form 7 plugin) with this query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)
```

So when I see it on a mobile device it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1hEM.png) (good enough for now)

But when I click on a text field the "screen" flips and look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHiqW.png)  and I don't know why. Please help me.

Relevant code:

HTML

```
<div id="div-mail">
[contact-form-7 id="95" title="formulario de contacto"]
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div-mail {
position: relative;
right: -35px !important;
bottom: 270px !important;
max-width: 80%;
z-index:2;
top: -365px;
}
```

Contact form 7 text fields CSS

```
#contact-email {
max-width: 65% !important;
}

#contact-textarea {
max-width: 70% !important;
}
```

Comment: Most likely happening because the viewport size changes when the keyboard tray is open.  Why would you force a portrait mode on someone? Goes against the grain of a fluid web and all these wonderful devices we have available.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent (or confirm) that? I know about the problems with forcing a portrait mode but that's the way it works for now